# Build openSmile lib with VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build audEERING UG's openSmile library on Windows. I need to use this library with VS2005 but because setup with VS2005 isn't supported - my idea is to build it on VS2010 and then connect to VS2005 project. I can't somehow make it work so I will write step by step what I do:

1. I download latest openSMILE 2.1 version from official website: http://www.audeering.com/research/opensmile#installation
2. I open http://www.audeering.com/research-and-open-source/files/openSMILE-book-latest.pdf and read setup section for Windows
3. I open ide/vs10/openSmile.sln file with VS2010 and get this error:

   ```
   error  : Project "E:\Workplace\openSMILE-2.1.0\thirdparty\portaudio\build\msvc\portaudio.vcxproj" could not be found.
   ```

   But I read in documentation that PortAudio is only one of variants so I ignore problem as I don't use it in my project:

   You can select several configurations from this solution which represent the various combinations
   of the standalone version (simply Release and Debug configurations) and support of OpenCV
   and PortAudio (named accordingly).
4. I build openSmileLibClassif manually - done.
5. I build openSmileLibLibsvm manually - done.
6. I don't do anything iwth openSmileLibPortaudio
7. I build SMILEExtract manually and get an error:

   ```
   error MSB4019: The imported project "E:\Workplace\openSMILE-2.1.0\openSMILE-2.1.0\ide\vs10\gnuGpl.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
   ```

   I check in the project directory if there is gnuGpl.props file but I can't find it. I try to download previous version of the lib then: openSMILE-2.0-rc1. After unzip there is an gnuGpl.props file in the previous version. I copy it to 2.1 version.
8. Try to build SMILEExtract again. I get other error:

   ```
   2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(E:\Workplace\openSMILE-2.1.0\openSMILE-2.1.0\ide\vs10\Debug\SMILExtract_Debug.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (E:\Workplace\openSMILE-2.1.0\msvcbuild\SMILExtract_Debug.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
   2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'E:\Workplace\openSMILE-2.1.0\msvcbuild\openSmileLib_Debug.lib'
   ```
9. I think that maybe copying gnuGpl.props from previous project to new one is bad idea so I try to build openSMILE-2.0-rc1 instead and I get same error as in point 8.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After I've deleted openSmileLibPortaudio from my project directory (because usage of it disables ASIO and I need it) and compiled project 3 times errors disappeared and I have only warning about considering output file location.

Answer (score 0):

change your mode from debug to release!

in manual:
Important note for building on Windows: Some versions of Visual Studio
always select the "Debug" configuration by default instead of the "Release" configuration.
However, you always want to build the "Release" configuration, unless you are
an openSMILE developer. Thus, you mus always select the "Release" configuration
from the drop-down menu, before clicking on "Build Solution" !!

Answer (score 0):

right mouse-key on`openSmileLib` go to `project->add->exist item`,
choose `src\examples\simpleMessageSender.cpp` and click `add to openSmileLib project`, finally, recompile the code.