# Building OPENSMILE with portaudio in vs2012 fail

Tags: c++, linker, wav, feature-extraction

I am trying to build audEERING UG's openSmile library on Windows.

I have successfully build the OPENSMILE before with using the portaudio
by following the guide [Compiling without portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801345/build-opensmile-lib-with-vs2010).

Now I need to do extract features from live, using OpenSMILE with port audio.
So I try follow the other link steps [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379453/build-opensmile-with-vs2010-fail) but i get the error of

[image: https://goo.gl/photos/vrZV43MJXZMoR7qr5]

Thus I try comment out that portion and rebuild it successfully.

So the following steps is as followed

1. build openSmileLibClassif manually - done.
2. build openSmileLibLibsvm manually - done.
3. build openSmileLibPortaudio –done.

   But when building openSmileLib, this is the error i get:

[image]

does anyone know how to solve this?

I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please copy and paste stacktraces, do not make screenshots of them.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin thx for asking the stacktraces, but it seems like after recompiling the code again it seems fine now.                                             I'm not sure why but is definitely working. Perhaps the problem lies in the configuration manager where I choose x64 platform instead of win32.

Comment: Since you've found the solution, it's worth to write an answer (you can give answers to your own questions). So your information will be useful to somebody who faces the same problem in the future.

Comment: I would posting my answer in a document and share it once I done with it.

Comment: I meant answering it here, on SO. Don't quite understand, what you meant by "in a document". :-) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/